# sfValidator value == string

Tags: symfony1, validation, symfony-1.4

How can I check in symfony 1.4 if a value is a specific string.

In my html-code I enter a default-value:

```
<input ... value="Recipe name.">
```

My current form:

```
$recipename_value = 'Recipe name.';
$this->setWidgets(array(
        'recipename' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('size' => '40', 'maxlength' => '150',
        'value' => $recipename_value,

$this->setValidators(array(
        'recipename' => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 150), array(
        'required' => 'Please enter a recipe name.'
        )),
```

The sfValidator should give an error message when the value is `Recipe name.` How can I do it in symfony? I read a lot about max_- & min_length and sfValidatorSchemaCompare, but nothing with string. Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Gunnar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use postValidator
In your form class:

```
public function checkValue($validator, $values) {

  if ($values['recipename']=="Recipe name."){

     $message = 'Your message';
     throw new sfValidatorError($validator, $message);

  }
  else{
       return $values; 
       }
  }
```

**BUT** , I think the true way for you is to use placeholder for your form field. You can read about it:

**[HTML5  placeholder Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp)**

And plugin for IE:

**[jQuery HTML5 Placeholder Plugin](http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/)**